# Get Unique Active Users With One Last Four SSN and Other Conditions

Tags: sql-server, view, unique

I have a table where employees sometimes change names, become full-time employees under another ID (FTEs get get different ID from PeopleSoft, and contractors IDs are dumps from recruiters), and some even have same first, middle, last and last 4 SSN. Because the table has mix of full-time and contractors and dupes of identical name and ssn, I'm not 100% on uniqueness of the table.

I need a view that meets the following conditions:

- First name
- Last Name
- Employee ID
- Status (active, terminated)
- Last 4 SSN (0000)

Conditions:

- Get all names where they only share one last four of SSN
- Show Just the active record if both Active and Terminated are available (maybe became full time, or rehired contractor under another ID from different agency)
- Remove all records where there are 2+ Terminated or 2+ Active records

Comment: Why do you assume that last 4 digits of an SSN is unique? This is like expecting everyone's PIN number to be unique. While likely, there is no guarantee. In other words, how can you tell if John Smith / 4466 and Jack Smith / 4466 are different people, or the same person who changed their name, or the system made a mistake on one or both pieces of data?

Answer (score 0):

Following your logic, it looks like you're only looking for records where the same LastFourSSN appear for one Active and one Terminated status (since there are only two statuses, and you exclude instances where 2+ active or 2+ terminated, the only possibilities of multiple LastFourSSNs are ones with 1 active and 1 terminated).

Using that logic, something like this could be constructed, which returns records where there's only 1 active record that matches a terminated record (from a list of terminated records with only one entry) and since every record has to match a terminated one, we will return only the ones that have the status 'Active':

```
select 
    FirstName
    ,LastName
    ,EmployeeID
    ,Status
    ,LastFourSSN
from 
    tblPeople
where
    Status = 'Active'
    and LastFourSSN in 
    (
        /*selected only entries with 1 active*/
        select
            LastFourSSN
        from 
            tblPeople
        where 
            Status = 'Active'
            and LastFourSSN in /*only show entries with matching termination record*/
                (
                    /*selected only entries with 1 termination*/
                    select
                        LastFourSSN
                    from 
                        tblPeople
                    where 
                        Status = 'Terminated'
                    group by 
                        LastFourSSN
                    having 
                        count(*) = 1
                )
        group by 
            LastFourSSN
        having 
            count(*) = 1
    )
```